# Show only tabs using actionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm building an application using actionbarSherlock, and i'm using tabs in one of my actives.
Is it possible to show only the tabs and hide the bar ?

In the left is how it's actually displayed and in the right it's how i would like to display

[image: action_bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solutions is :

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  
bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set correct theme. In your manifest file, add this to your activity declaration:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

**EDIT**

You can hide titlebar from code as well. Add this to your activity's onCreate():

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

**EDIT 3**

You could always create own style, derriving from sherlocks' and add disable of title bar. Like this

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and then make activity using MyTheme

Comment: i tyied but,i got an exception:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.guitcastro.rachaconta/br.com.guitcastro.rachaconta.activity.TabsFragmentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.

Comment: thanks for the help. But i'm geting NullPointer when i call requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: I couldn't find Theme.Sherlock.NoTitleBar on sherlock =/

Comment: Hm, seems [Theme.Sherlock.NoTitleBar is just unresolved wish](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/146)

Comment: this doesn't worked either, but i found the solution!
I'll give you plus one, thank you so much!

Comment: Post the solution in comment, so others could save some time while having the same problem